# Node.js web scraping optimization

Tags: node.js, web-scraping

**Tasks:**

1. Scrape html from a webpage
2. Parse the html
3. Clean the data (remove white space, perform basic regex)
4. Persist the data to a SQL database.

Goal is to complete these 4 tasks as quickly as possible and here are some possible example approaches.

**Possible Sample Approaches**

Multi-Step 1: Scrape all pages and store html as .txt files.  After all html is stored as text, run a separate module that parses/cleans/persists the data.

Multi-step 2: Scrape/Parse/Clean data and store in .txt files.  Run a separate module to insert the data into a database.

Single-Step: Scrape/Parse/Clean/Persist data all in one step.

**Assumptions:**

1. 1 dedicated server being used for scraping
2. disk space is unlimited
3. internet connection is your average home connection
4. memory (8GB)
5. No rate limiting on any web pages
6. User wants to scrape 1 million pages

I haven't done enough testing with node.js to establish a best practice **but any insight on optimizing these tasks would be greatly appreciated.**

Obviously, there are some unanswered questions (how much html is on a typical page, how much are your parsing, request/response latency, what frameworks are being used to parse data...etc), but a high level best practice/key considerations would be beneficial.  Thanks.

Comment: If you're using node.js, you will definitely want to get multiple CPUs involved so you would either want to cluster node.js or offload parsing and other work to child processes.  It will take lots of measurement on an initial implementation to figure out where your bottleneck is and what direction you should improve things after your first implementation.  This is generally something that cannot be entirely predicted in advance.  Get something working, measure, adapt, measure again, adapt again.  Your performance measurement process will be as important too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a problem like this, you can forsee only certain aspects of what will really control where your bottlenecks will be.  So, you start with a smart, but not complicated implementation and you spend a fair amount of time figuring out how you can measure your performance and where the bottlenecks are.

Then, based on the knowledge of where the bottlenecks are, you come up with a proposed design change, implement that change and see how much of a difference you made in your overall throughput.  You then instrument again, measure again and see where your new bottleneck is, come up with a new theory on how to beat that bottleneck, implement, measure, theorize, iterate, etc...

You really don't want to overdesign or overcomplicate the first implementation because it's very easy to be wrong about where you think the real bottleneck will be.

So, I'd probably start out with a design like this:

Create one node.js process that doesn't absolutely nothing but download pages and write them to disk.  Use nothing by async I/O everywhere and make it configurable for how many simultaneous page downloads it has in-flight at once.  Do no parsing, just write the raw data to disk.  You will want to find some very fast way of storing which URL is which file.  That could be something as simple as appending info to a text file or it could be a database write, but the idea is you just want it to be fast.

Then, create another node.js process that repeatedly grabs files from disk, parses them, cleans the data and persists the data to your SQL database.

Run the first node.js process by itself and let it run until it collects either 1,000 web pages or for 15 minutes (whichever comes first) to measure how much throughput you're initially capable of.  While it's running, note the CPU utilization and the network utilization on your computer.  If you're already in the ballpark of what you might need for this first node.js process, then you're done with the first node.js process.  If you want it go much faster, then you need to figure out where your bottleneck is.  If you're CPU-bound (unlikely for this I/O task), then you can cluster and run multiple of these node.js processes, giving each one a set of URLs to fetch and a separate place to write their collected data.  More than likely you're I/O bound.  This may be either because you aren't fully saturating your existing network connection (the node.js process spends too much time waiting for I/O) or you have already saturated your network connection and it is now the bottleneck.   You will have to figure out which of these it is.  If you add more simultaneous web page fetches and the performance does not increase or even goes down, then you've probably already saturated your web connection.  You will also have to watch out for saturation the file I/O sub-system in node.js which uses a limit thread pool to implement async I/O.

For the second node.js process, you follow a similar process.  Give it 1,000 web pages and see how fast it can process them all.  Since you do have I/O to read the files form disk and to write to the database, you will want to have more than one page parsing at a time so you can maximize usage of the CPU when one page is being read in or written out.  You can either write one node.js process to handle multiple parse projects at once or you can cluster a single node.js process.  If you have multiple CPUs in your server, then you will want to have at least as many process as you have CPUs probably.  Unlike the URL fetcher process, the code for parsing is likely something that could be seriously optimized to be faster.  But, like other performance issues, don't try to overly optimize that code until you know you are CPU bound and it is holding you up.

Then, if your SQL database can be on another box or at least using another disk, that's probably a good thing because it separates out the disk writes there from your other disk writes.

Where you go after the first couple steps will depend entirely upon what you learn from the first few steps.  Your ability to measure where the bottlenecks are and design quick experiments to test bottleneck theories will be hugely important for making rapid progress and not wasting development time on the wrong optimizations.

FYI, some home internet connection ISPs may set off some alarms with the amount and rate of your data requests.  What they will do with that info likely varies a lot from one ISP to the next.  I would think that most ultimately have some ability to rate limit your connection to protect the quality of service for others sharing your same pipe, but I don't know when/if they would do that.

This sounds like a really fun project to try to optimize and get the most out of.  It would make a great final project for a medium to advanced software class.